# Collapsed regions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-sdk

I'm doing a Visual Studio extension and it contains editor margin, which show comment for each code line and data linked by line number.

When I have code have collapsed regions (functions, code blocks or regions), I'm getting incorrect line numbers.

How can I calculate what lines collapsed? Or more simply, how can I expand all collapsed blocks and disable collapse buttons?

Comment: are you sure that you have all matching `#endregion` for your beginning `#region ~~~ ` code..? `~` = your region name

Comment: Problem not only in #regions. Function can be collapsed too

Comment: This is either unclear, or too broad. Could you either expand a bit / give some example / show what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

```
    Dim _outliningManager As Outlining.IOutliningManager
Dim _oldCollapsedRegions As List(Of ICollapsed)

'Getting access to ServiceProvider
<Import>
Dim ServiceProvider As SVsServiceProvider

'Getting IOutliningManagerService object
 Dim componentModel As IComponentModel = ServiceProvider.GetService(GetType(SComponentModel))
 Dim outliningManagerService As IOutliningManagerService = componentModel.GetService(Of IOutliningManagerService)()

    'Creating IOutliningManager for current textView
    If outliningManagerService IsNot Nothing Then
        _outliningManager = outliningManagerService.GetOutliningManager(textView)
        If _outliningManager IsNot Nothing Then AddHandler _outliningManager.RegionsCollapsed, AddressOf RegionCollapsed

    End If

    'Getting all regions and expand them
    If _outliningManager IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim snapshot = _textView.TextSnapshot
        Dim snapshotSpan = New Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.SnapshotSpan(snapshot, New Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Span(0, snapshot.Length))
        _oldCollapsedRegions = _outliningManager.GetCollapsedRegions(snapshotSpan).ToList()
        For Each reg In _oldCollapsedRegions
            _outliningManager.Expand(reg)
        Next
    End If


'Blocking regions collapsed
Sub RegionCollapsed(sender As Object, e As RegionsCollapsedEventArgs)
    If Me.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible Then
        For Each reg In e.CollapsedRegions
            _outliningManager.Expand(reg)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Require referenses to:  microsoft.visualstudio.shell.immutable.10.0, Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost and, sure, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text